# Дописать строку в конец ячейки (PHP MYSQL)

Tags: php

Есть цикл Foreach.
Он добавляет строку в ячейку (в БД)
Сам запрос лежит в цикле.

Запрос:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE content SET news='$element' WHERE id='$id'", $db);
```

все работает нормально, кроме  - добавляется только последняя строка из цикла фореч. Т.е. он просто перезаписывает.

Мне нужно дописать в конец ячейки строку.

---

Пробовал

> =concat

Он записывает в БД пустые строки. 
Вот код целиком:

```
    $i=1;
foreach($html->find('td div[style] a') as $element) //
{
       $elemen = iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $element); $element->plaintext
      if(isset($element->{'alt'})  === $element->{'alt'})
          {
            echo"";
          }
else 
{
    //echo $elemen . "<br>"; 
    $elemen = " $elemen";
    echo $elemen;
     mysql_query("UPDATE content SET linkfulnews='$elemen' WHERE kluch='$kluch'", $db);
        $i++;
}  
}
$html->clear(); // подчищаем за собой, чтобы не было утечки данных
unset($html); // Удаляем переменную с ДОМ
}
```

Comment: Добавил в исходный код в старт пост. Выше кода, только получение ссылок и прочее. Я пока экспериментирую с ним, поэтому много всякой ненужной ерунды в коде. Как сделаю, почищу.

Answer (score 2):

Оно и будет перезаписываться, ведь цикл по очереди перебирает данные. И естественно последнее что он выведет и будет записано. А вам, нужно что бы данные в переменную не просто записывались, а добавлялись. Я примерно представляю, что  вы хотите, но недостаточно данных. Вот к примеру, как бы я дописывал данные в переменную `$a .= $a`  `.=` Добавляет данные в переменную, не перезаписывая ее.

Comment: Хороший ход мыслей. Как я не додумался. пойду попробую.

Comment: А вообще вот так же UPDATE `table` SET `data` = CONCAT(`data`,  'новые данные') WHERE  `id` =1 LIMIT  1 Вместо ID естественно ваше значение в таблице.

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php

устаревшая функция, переписывайте под PDO.
если по теме вопроса, то нужен код цикла целиком.

---

строку в конец ячейки - это в $elemen, `$a = $elemen.PHP_EOL.'новая строка';`

Comment: Или на mysqli_*